# How to navigate to another wpf page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I tried to navigate to another wpf page but it doesn't work at all. Here's what I've been using:

C#:

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Doelen nextPage = new Doelen();
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <Button x:Name="btnNext" Content="Volgende" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="btnNext_Click"/>
```

The big problem here is that Visual Studio says that there is no *Navigate* in *NavigationService*.

Can anyone tell me what I`m doing wrong?

For full code see picture below:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a Button to navigate to another Page in a NavigationWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803921/using-a-button-to-navigate-to-another-page-in-a-navigationwindow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `this` pointer and be explicit on your routedeventargs.

```
    using System.Windows.Navigation;

within:

public partial class MyPage : Page


private void btnNext_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Doelen nextPage = new Doelen();
    NavigationService.Navigate(nextPage);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to add *NavigationService* after *this*, eventhough I've implemented System.Windows.Navigation;

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationWindow nw = new NavigationWindow();
nw.Content = new Doelen();
nw.ShowDialog();
```

or nw.Show():

you may need a nw.Initialze();

Comment: This code doesn't give me an error, however, it won't show Doelen